# java refactoring - moving enum to a different package without changing imports

Tags: java, enums, refactoring

*Update: **I'm really not looking for tips how to change company processes**, how to throw the problem at others, etc. Rather, **I was hoping to find if there is some obscure bit of Java knowledge** that would allow me to abuse Enums for a temporary workaround. After asking this question, **I managed to** find a quieter period and **release my change**. But I'm still curious if there is something in the dark corners of Java that could be helpful in a situation like this.*

I have a huge, old (but still actively developed) codebase in Java with dozens of packages and I need to move an enum between them.

There is this enum that's inside of a class:

```
package com.foo.bar;
public class ParentClass
{
    public Enum MyEnum
    {
        ONE, TWO;
    }
}
```

This enum is widely used across the entire application. I need to extract it from the parent class and move it into a different package:

```
package com.enums;
public Enum MyEnum
{
    ONE, TWO;
}
```

The standard way how to do it is a simple refactoring with the use of IDE. Which works. But... This leads to changes in many places and because the codebase is actively developed by different teams and many people, I keep getting merge conflicts, new usages of this enum are appearing, and so on. So I'm stuck in a whack-a-mole situation. I bring my change up to date, run test suites and build it, but before that is done (the whole loop takes at least a day, not speaking about a new code review), I end up with another conflict. Rinse, repeat.

Telling everyone to stop working while I merge this is not possible. If it was a normal class and not an enum, I could try to use inheritance: move it to the new location and replace the original location with an empty child class, and then deal with the usages one by one. But Java enums can't be extended.

Is there any way how I could break this change into multiple stages (so I do not need to change all the imports where it is used) instead of having to do it all at once, in an atomic change?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand the problem here. Do the refactoring on a separate branch. Let the IDE move your enum. Push the branch and notify the others that there's a big change, so they can pull that branch. I don't see why there's the need for "Rinse and Repeat" here, it's a one-off action. If they commit regularly and merge new changes regularly into their feature branches, there shouldn't be any issues. If not, then that's a "Them" problem. If you're all working on the same branch all the time, or no branches at all, or directly on "master", then it's time to rework your git work flow.

Comment: @QBrute: Too large project with thousands of people working on it daily, and I need to change too many places at once. Every time I solve one merge conflict, it takes about a day before I can really merge it (test builds, review...) and by that time, new conflict pops out so I can't merge and have to solve the new one. And there is no chance I can change the company workflow or make everyone stop for a couple of days.

Comment: And **your** branch shouldn’t have merge conflicts; **theirs** may, and they need to resolve them.

Comment: If they merge their changes before I do, it's my branch that has a conflict.  And usually there is no problem, I just need to rename something that's used very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy from your comment above, since my answer will be referencing it.

***@QBrute: Too large project with thousands of people working on it daily, and I need to change too many places at once. Every time I solve one merge conflict, it takes about a day before I can really merge it (test builds, review...) and by that time, new conflict pops out so I can't merge and have to solve the new one. And there is no chance I can change the company workflow or make everyone stop for a couple of days***

I'll start off by saying that, based off the little info you gave us, your coworkers and the company process for handling package rearrangements seem to be the ones at fault here. But you also mentioned that you can't really change the company workflow easily.

The part that stuck out to me was you saying that testing the merge conflict fix would take a full day. Maybe, instead of making the code change yourself, you should add a unit test instead.

The unit test should be simple.

- Check to see if the old enum is found on the class/module path. Fail if true.
- Check to see if the new enum is found on the class/module path. Fail if false.

When these tests fail, add a braindead simple error message that tells your coworkers ***EXACTLY*** what they need to do to fix this unit test. The unit test should also help slow down the incoming code because a failed unit test should prevent new builds from going out. Plus, a failed unit test should allow this to show up front and center to your fellow developers (assuming they check/respond to unit test failures).

Since adding a unit test is a non-functional change (and shouldn't even exist in your deployed library/executable), you can skip the whole test/review/deploy cycle that seems to be taking you so long. You simply commit then merge.

You would need to do it for basically every project though. Should be a simple copy and paste though.

Comment: Are you suggesting merging a red/broken test?

Comment: @Sören as a last resort to a team that is too inflexible to adapt to something as simple as a package rename? Correct, I am.

Comment: If I added a test like that, it starts failing in all builds and devops will stomp me into the ground and back it out. And I can't skip the other tests, because without it, I don't know if I didn't just break something really important and now tens of thousands of tests are red... At the end, I managed to get my change through today by waiting for a weekend. 

Anyway, I know how the process here works and what could be done better. What I was hoping for was to find out if there is some Java hack that should generally be avoided, but I can use it as a temporary workaround.

Comment: @Zopper I see that your question has an update at the top. That definitely should have been there in the first place, as we could have given you a more definitive answer. The simple answer is no, that is not possible. You have an enum that exists in the same dependency but a different package, and you want other programs/libraries/applications to somehow work? Not possible. That said, maybe you can describe what you were hoping to find and then we might be able to find out more info that may make things possible.